# Mixed content block by browser version

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser, blocking

I need to clearly know from what version of all browsers 'mixed content blockade' was implemented.

For now I know this:

- Firefox - from version 23 (I am 100% sure about this)
- Chrome - from version 20 (I found this on some google groups post)
- IE - unknown
- Opera - unknown
- Safari - unknown
- ...

Thanks for help.

Comment: IE has been doing this for ages, since version 7. Here is a reference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have determined exact browser versions from which **"mixed content blockade"** is implemented in every browser:

- chrome = 30
- safari = 5.1
- opera = 30 // same as chrome since it uses webkit/blink as rendering engine from version 15
- firefox = 23
- internet explorer = 8

Thanks to guys on javascript chat for pointing on http://www.browserstack.com for easy cross browser testing...